# nodejs in windows file system path error 4058 ENOENT

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, file, filesystems

I am using [file system with nodejs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_readstream_path) in `windows` to write process logs. I have follwing code

```
var fs = require('fs');
var config = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('config.json', 'utf8'));
var statusLogStream = fs.createWriteStream("../logs/load stat"+(new Date())+".log");
```

It turns out with an error

```
    { [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\proc\logs\load stat Mon Apr 18 2016 19:09:32 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time).log']
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'C:\\proc\\logs\\load stat Mon Apr 18 2016 19:09:32 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time).log' }
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^
```

I try the folder to open the file manually `C:\\proc\\logs` it doesn't work and `C:/proc/logs` this when I replace double backward slash by forward slash I can manually open the folder from explorer.

How to make it working

Why is it taking the `double backward slash` instead of `forward slash`

**IMP: The above code works perfectly fine in `linux ubuntu` server but not in `windows`**

Comment: @Tresdin : That's something I too know frankly however what code change do I need to make to above code to make it working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is not about the slashes but on how the date is converted to string.

I bet this will work:

```
var statusLogStream = fs.createWriteStream("../logs/load stat.log");
```

**Update**
Windows is complaining about the two colons in the string representation of date (`Mon Apr 18 2016 19**:**09**:**32 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`)

This could be a good alternative:

```
var myDate = new Date().toJSON().replace(new RegExp(':', 'g'),'.');
// myDate is now "2016-04-18T15.19.21.174Z"
var statusLogStream = fs.createWriteStream("../logs/load stat"+(myDate)+".log");
```

Comment: How did you figure out that? I was clue less.

Comment: I first tried with a simple test `./loadstat.log` to check the slash issue. then I added a piece at a time until I got the error. In particular windows is complaining about the presence of two `:` in the file name. Still investigating on why...

Comment: When using Nodes on windows platform I found that folder names with special characters like '*' and also endings with '.' are causing problems... for that reason we always 'normalize' filenames and folder names before using them in IO operations...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

In my project when I ran an express app I noticed that the current working directory was the root directory of the project (while I was trying to read a file that was located in the script's directory).
It could not run the file since `process.cwd() !== __dirname`.

You can check it out and console log `process.cwd()` in the script you are trying to read the json file.

I just changed the the path to:

```
const fs = require('fs');
fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}\\FILENAME`);
```